# How do I use a Restore Point saved to a drive other than C:?

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

Windows offers you the feature of using system protection on drives other than C.
You open 'System Properties' and then go to the 'System Protection' tab, you have the option of enabling it and creating restore points on every drive installed.

The problem is that you can't restore them. Upon launching System Restore, windows will show only the restore points in the C drive, and if you have none there, it will tell you no restore point is present in the system drive.

Comment: What my system says is "Create a Restore Point for the drives that have System Protection turned on" So you need to enable System Protection for those drives, but the restore points are still on Drive C:

Comment: @John Hi. I think you may not be aware of it, but there's actually a way to create the restore points on other drives and they do get stored there. 

I'll later add some screenshots to the question, but if you click over the drive name and then click 'create' the restore poing gets stored in that same drive (you can see it there using tools like TreeSize).
Otherwise what would be the point of having the settings to **reserve disk space** in these drives?

Comment: I think you might be correct if there is applications on other drives. I have a system here here C: and D: and only data on D:  Tree Size shows System Volume Information and Recycle Bin all empty. The management structure of returning to a Restore Point is managed from Drive C: - I am fairly sure of that. As a matter of good management, I keep OS and Programs on C: always - only data on drive D: and beyond.

Comment: @John now, I think you're right when you say that restore points are managed from the C drive. All the restore points created automatically go to the C: drive.

Now, my C drive is backed up every day. I noticed restore points eat a significant amount of space in those backups. Disabling them seems overall a bad idea, so I started creating them on other drives. Here treesize shows a 7.7GB folder within System Volume Information, which matches what the "System Protection" tab shows as being used for that drive.

Comment: Sounds appropriate. I do not place much faith in restore points and keep usage to about 6 GB. I have only used them 2 or 3 times in the last 20 or 25 years.

Comment: @John, therefore, I have absolutely no doubt restore points can and are being created within other drives.

The problem is that there's virtually no way to restore them that I know of. I could move the restore point folder in 'System Volume Info' into the C drive, but doing that would probably result in a tremendous mess with permissions.